# Meteor 0.8.0 with Cordova 3.4.0

Tags: cordova, meteor

I have a Meteor 0.8 project that I'm trying to integrate with Google and Apple push notifications through a Cordova plugin I've already wrote the works for a different project.  I'm using this [plugin](https://github.com/SpaceCapsule/Meteor-cordova/) that's been recommended with previous releases of Meteor but after reading this [post](https://github.com/SpaceCapsule/Meteor-cordova/issues/15), I'm not sure if this plugin is useful any more.

In my meteor project I have the following code that gets called at startup to get the current version:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log("initiating cordova...");
    var cordova = new cordova();

    var version = {
        appVersion: function (args, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            if (is.iOS) {
                cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PackageInfo", "getVersion", args);

            } else if (is.Android) {
                cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PackageInfo", "getVersion", args);
            }
        }
    };

    alert("Current Version:  " + version.appVersion());

});
```

In my Cordova project, I have the following code to iframe Meteor:

```
<iframe id="meteor" src="http://meteor-cord.meteor.com">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">

    shellVersion = '0.0.1';

    meteor = new MeteorCordova('meteor'); // The iFrame id "meteor"

    // meteor.initPush({ senderID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' });

</script>
```

Any ideas on how to get this working so that I can use Cordova plugins with the latest version of Meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried MeteorCordova earlier but had a lot of issues with iOS and keyboard/text input events. I ended up switching over to MeteorRider which solved a lot of issues. It basically fetches the html from the server and injects it into the index.html and re-fires the Meteor events. We're using it on Android and iOS.

You can then use the PhoneGap plugin API's in the same manner as you would with a local index.html.

I've created a drop in boilerplate for iOS and PhoneGap 3.3 (3.4 should also work fine).
https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-cordova-shell

You can also just copy paste the www folder in the rep. and change the bottom part of index.html to point to your meteor server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // use this to track what version your user's are running
  var __MeteorRiderConfig__ = {
    // Your production meteor app
    meteorUrl:  "http://leaderboard.meteor.com/",

    // Your local dev meteor server url                        
    //meteorUrl:  "http://192.168.1.XX:3000",

    // Cordova version, bump this after a `cordova update <platform>`
    phonegapVersion: 3.3,

    phonegapAppVersion: 0.1
  };

  // Start up the phonegap
  phonegapapp.initialize();
</script>
```

And then you can call your `PackageInfo.getVersion()` if that's still applicable. You can then do things like `device.platform` etc... I've also open sourced a few Meteor packages to make the ready/offline/etc cordova/phonegap events reactive, Meteor Phonegap Oauth, and a few others.

Comment: I have looked at this approach but the author of MeteorRider even says that if you're using PhoneGap plugins, you should use the Meteor Cordova: https://github.com/zeroasterisk/MeteorRider. I specifically need to be able to do push notifications.  Have you had success doing that with MeteorRider? I'm going to check this out today and will respond back if I'm successful.

Comment: I have the app showing up on my iPhone but how can I call out to Cordova plugin from my meteor app (specifically the app being injected into the /www index.html of the Cordova app)?

Comment: Ah, so you can just use the vanilla PhoneGap API in your Meteor code. No plugins necessary. For ex. if you have the device phonegap plugin you can just use if `(device.platform === 'iOS')` The only caveat is that the device ready event has to fire. So code running at startup could run before that happens, so I either add a listener  in the docs inside of a meteor.startup function.

Comment: Hmmm...was getting "device is not defined" error, but I think it was just a function of it not being reloaded properly. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention, the device global is only available if you install the device plugin: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into packmeteor, it seems to be the most up-to-date way to go.

[Pack Meteor on GitHub](https://github.com/SpaceCapsule/packmeteor)

Answer (score 0):

I just published a new package that fixes the issues with the methods mentioned. Installation and setup are really straight forward. Check the readme. Works with Cordova 3.5.

---

## Overview

Cordova Loader's goal is to make using Meteor with Cordova as easy as using Meteor itself. The compiler interprets the provided Cordova project directory and compiles the assets into minified, platform-specific JavaScript files that are placed in the Meteor /public directory. When the client loads, it automatically pulls in the platform-specific file for that device. The Cordova API can be used from Meteor the same as it is from vanilla JS apps. Enjoy!

[Cordova Loader](https://github.com/andrewreedy/meteor-cordova-loader)

---

#### Comparison with methods described [here](http://zeroasterisk.com/2013/08/22/meteor-phonegapcordova-roundup-fall-2013/)

- Lazy Loading (cordova-phonegap): Hard to manage all of the Cordova dependencies / Unfinished / Outdated
- Hijack (meteor-rider): Slow initial load / Can't use appcache / Issues with plugins.
- iFrame (meteor-cordova): iFrames generally are a pain including slow performance in native apps, glitchy scrolling, and having to wrap Cordova
- Cordova Loader:

  - Manages assets for you
  - Fast loading
  - Compatible with appcache
  - Compatible with Cordova plugins
  - No need for wrapper around Cordova
  - Minifies platform specific bundles
  - Automatically lazy loads platform specific bundles in client
  - Watches Cordova project plugin directory for changes